# How to perform a Goral HaGra

Tags: tanach

How is a Goral HaGra performed? Is there a special book I use? What is the proper procedure?

Do you just open it up and see what Pasuk you land on?

What do you do?

Comment: People who are holy enough to do it, are taught how to by tradition handed down from one tzaddik to another. Others should stay far away.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but I believe that only a particular type of book can be used as the 'Bible'. It may not work with just any chumash. I'm not even sure a chumash is enough, perhaps you need a tanach. I'm also pretty sure it's not meant for the masses - it probably can't be done by just anybody. In any case, as @Miriam pointed out, it's quite unwise (to say the least) to base your performance of this ritual on an account in a biography, especially if you plan to act on it. It may even be forbidden to do so.

Comment: it's one thing to know how to do it and another to do it successfully. you have to be a very holy man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See page 165 in A Tzaddik In Our Time by Simcha Raz for an account of the procedure:

> Reb Aryeh opened the Bible entirely at random, to whatever page chance
>   would bring him. Then he continued turning batches of pages this way
>   and that, haphazardly, seven times. Now he turned over exactly seven
>   single leaves, going forward. Next, he went forward seven single
>   pages; after that, seven columns; then seve verses; then seven words
>   and finally seven single letters. Thus it was seven times seven: seven
>   batches, leaves, pages, columns, verses, words letters. Whatever
>   seventh letter was, Reb Aryeh now looked for the the very next verse
>   which began with that letter. By the verses of Scripture found in this
>   way, he would assign a name to each of the twelve un identified
>   soldiers who now lay reburied in the milita cemetery on Mount Herzl.

Comment: More details there: "They started by saying Tehillim.... By tradition a certain Hebrew Bible, 2 columns to a page printed in Amsterdam in 1701 ..."

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but I believe that only a particular type of book can be used as the 'Bible'. It may not work with just any chumash. I'm not even sure a chumash is enough, perhaps you need a tanach. I'm also pretty sure it's not meant for the masses - it probably can't be done by just anybody. In any case, as @Miriam pointed out, it's quite unwise (to say the least) to base your performance of this ritual on an account in a biography, especially if you plan to act on it. It may even be forbidden to do so.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://strangeside.com/vilna-gaon-his-lottery/) might be of help.

> ...One of the earliest poskim to discuss the practice of
>   performing goralos with seforim is the Maharikash (Rav Yaakov Kastro
>   of Egypt, died about 1610, cited by the Chida’s Shiyurei Berocha) who
>   writes: “It seems to me that all agree one may open a Sefer Torah to
>   see which verse comes up, for it [the Torah] is our life. So we find
>   with Yeshayahu who took action after finding a Sefer Torah rolled to a
>   certain verse, and such is the general custom.” “The Chida finds
>   support for this practice from the following Yalkut (Mishlei 219):
>   “Have not I written for you excellent things in counsels and
>   knowledge (Mishlei 22:20). If you want to take counsel from the Torah,
>   you may do so. Dovid said: When I wanted to take counsel from the
>   Torah, I looked and took counsel as it says, I will speak of your
>   precepts, and perceive your ways (Tehillim 119:15), and it
>   says, Through Your precepts I will gain understanding (ibid 119:104).”
>   In addition, the Chida cites a manuscript of Rav Eliyahu Hakohen
>   (author of Shevet Mussar) that states: “I have a tradition from my
>   rabbis. When they wanted to know of some matter and were doubtful
>   whether to do it or not, they would take a Chumash or a Tanach, open
>   it, see what verse they found at the top of the page, and act
>   according to what it indicated. In this way, they took counsel with
>   the Torah concerning how to take action in all their concerns.....”

Answer (score 0):

Everyone’s purpose is in the tora.

1st Method.

Look at the Parashas you were born under, for men, it must be the barmitzva Parasha.

Step 2. There are seven days in a week there are seven aliyot. Go to the Alia that correlates to the day that you were born. In that Aliya you will find your purpose, though be aware it may be hidden or cryptic, feel free to share with me, I’ll try my best to deliver the proper message.

2nd Method also meant for everyone.
For difficult questions about what to do ect, from the  kitzur Shulchan Aruch.

Step 1. Use a TANACH,
Step 2. Netila,
Step 3. Focus on your question while focusing on the Tanach.
Step 4. Open the book, your answer should be the first pasuk on the top right. Caution, It may be cryptic.

The Goral, is literally the oracle, you must at all times be honest with your question, somewhat heartfelt (emotion), not emotional.  And most importantly with a clear mind. Any doubt in your question will throw the oracle off giving the incorrect answer. If you feel you did the steps correctly and you are not satisfied with the answer, please consult a Talmid hacham, he must know the question and the answer to properly provide the correct interpretation.

NOTE, not any Talmid hacham is capable, got to one that is familiar and confident within this area of judaism. Many are not sensitive to this topic and will disregard the whole thing while giving you an answer to just answer you though it may very well not be inline with what you're looking for. ( they are not bad people, just not educated).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any source for this?

Answer (score -2):

When dealing with a certain confusing issue I went to a well-respected Rav (whose would probably prefer that I don't mention his name) and he did a Goral Ha'Gra using an old, old Shas.